# Get S3 URL for APS

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

I'm following the steps from [this tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/#step-6-get-the-s3-url) to download a file from BIM360 using the Data Management API. I'm able to get up to step 5 without any issues. I can access the BIM360 file manually. In step 6 of the tutorial it the url has two parameters: bucket and object. I'm able to obtain the object from step 5. Where can I obtain the bucket parameter?

[Here is the documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3download-GET/) for the get signeds3download api.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the **step 5** response, you should get the `storage` part:

```
"storage": {
   "data": {
      "type": "objects",
      "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/977d69b1-43e7-40fa-8ece-6ec4602892f3.rvt"
    },
   "meta": {
      "link": {
         "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/977d69b1-43e7-40fa-8ece-6ec4602892f3.rvt"
         }
      }
   }
```

Either from `storage.data.id` or `storage.meta.link.href`, you can see that the **bucket** used by **BIM360** is `wip.dm.prod`.

This is the bucket used in the **step 6** of the [Download a file](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/#step-6-get-the-s3-url) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

AlexR is correct. you could find the bucket key and object key by that attribute of the document. This blog also describes about it
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/best-practice-uploading-and-downloading-files-bim360-docs
(note: this blog was written a few years ago, it directs to the old tutorial, but the way to extract bucket key and object key of BIM360 (or ACC) is still same as now)

Comment: Thank you Xiaodong Liang for the useful reference!